# Remove duplicates from elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a single index containing user information. I would like to make a search for documents matching either the NAME or EMAIL, give a count of matched documents for each and also a total count (NAME + EMAIL) with no duplicates between them. I was trying to use the aggregations, but dont quite seem to understand what to use.

Comment: is it exact match or partial match for name and email?

Comment: @bhoo-day Preferably an exact match